# What does 老得 mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> 我老得麻烦同事。

What does 老得 means in here? Does it mean

> I'm too old and have to bother colleagues constantly.

I find an [example](http://ting.eudic.net/webting/desktopplay?id=844fcdfc-2028-11e8-b7f2-000c29ffef9b&st=00:05:17.85),

> 我老得不能养猫了。
>
> I'm too old to have a cat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should take 老得 separately in this case.

老: *always; constantly*

得(dei3): *need; have to*

我老得麻烦同事 means *I have to bother colleagues constantly.*

In 我老得不能养猫了(I'm too old to have a cat), 得 is pronounced as *de* and 老 means *old*.

It relies on context to determine whether 得 is pronounced de or dei3, which reflects different meanings.